# AWS push notification shows "The security token included in the request is expired, __text"?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am having problem with aws push notification,

i am getting this error only on iPad, but its working in iPhone

```
Error occurred: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Type=Sender, Message=The security token included in the request is expired, __text=( 
"\n ", 
"\n ", 
"\n ", 
"\n " 
), Code=ExpiredToken}] 


AWSSNS *sns = [[AWSSNS new] initWithConfiguration:configuration]; 
AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *endpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new]; 
endpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = myArn; 
endpointRequest.token = strdeviceToken; 
__block AWSSNSSubscribeInput *subscribeRequest; 
__block AppDelegate *blocksafeSelf = self; 
[[[sns createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) 
{ 
AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *response = task.result; 
subscribeRequest = [AWSSNSSubscribeInput new]; 
subscribeRequest.topicArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:005"; 
subscribeRequest.endpoint = response.endpointArn; 
subscribeRequest.protocol = @"application"; 
endPoint = response.endpointArn; 
[blocksafeSelf CallNotificationSettings:endPoint]; 

//[blocksafeSelf CallNewsNotificationSettings:endPoint]; 
// [blocksafeSelf CallSportsNotificationSettings:endPoint]; 
//[blocksafeSelf CallEntertainmentNotificationSettings:endPoint]; 
return [sns subscribe:subscribeRequest]; 
}] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) 
{ 
if (task.cancelled) { 
NSLog(@"Task cancelled"); 
} 
else if (task.error) { 
NSLog(@"Error occurred: [%@]", task.error); 
} 
else { 
NSLog(@"Success %@",task.result); 
} 
return nil; 
}];
```

i am getting success response in iPhone

any idea?

Comment: AWSSNS *sns = [[AWSSNS new] initWithConfiguration:configuration], Is both devices use the same the same configuration, i mean same aws profile?

Comment: yes it is @omuthu